# setting a css property inside head tag using php

Tags: php, html, css

Suppose I have a preloader screen for my site. I want to set it randomly for each time the site loads. I want to make the **background** property of my css file random using php. Here is a a demo code for the css file:

```
<style>
   .se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;

   <?php
    $number=rand(1,4);
    $url=base_url('media');
    if($number==1)
    {
        echo "background:"."url(". $url."/images/loader-64x/infinity1.gif) center no-repeat #fff;";
    }
    if($number==2)
    {
        echo "background:"."url(". $url."/images/loader-64x/infinity2.gif) center no-repeat #fff;";

    }
    if($number==3)
    {
        echo "background:"."url(". $url."/images/loader-64x/infinity3.gif) center no-repeat #fff;";
    }
    if($number==4)
    {
          echo "background:"."url(". $url."/images/loader-64x/infinity4.gif) center no-repeat #fff;";
    }   
?>
}
</style>
```

I just want to make the **background** property different each time. But I think it's not working, as I am not getting any preloader screen at all. Is there any mistake in setting the background inside php?

Comment: Check what the generated html looks like (right click on the page and choose "view source" and see what it looks like.

Comment: This should work fine as long as you apply `.se-pre-con` to some element on your page that you want to apply the background to. Have you done that? `<div id="some_div" class="se-pre-con">`

Comment: Btw, instead of all the `if`-statements, you could just do: `echo "background: url({$url}/images/loader-64x/infinity{$number}.gif) center no-repeat #fff;";`

Comment: You could also try just setting a `background-color` on your div (make sure to remove ` #fff` on each image) and see if that color is applied then you will know if your image path is wrong at least and then work towards fixing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with base_url function in xampp. Use the below code instead and its working fine for me if you are having the images in correct location

```
<style>
    .se-pre-con{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    <?php
    $number=rand(1,2);
    $url='media';
    if($number==1)
    echo "background:url('".$url."/images/loader-64x/infinity1.gif') center no-repeat #fff;";
    else if($number==2)
        echo "background:url('".$url."/images/loader-64x/infinity2.gif') center no-repeat #fff;";
    ?>
    }
</style>
```

How ever I have a better solution, play php with html not css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
   .se-pre-con{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    }
    .bg1{
        background:url('media/1.jpg') center no-repeat #fff;
    }
    .bg2{
        background:url('media/2.jpg') center no-repeat #fff;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="se-pre-con <?php $arr=array('bg1','bg2'); echo $arr[array_rand($arr)];?>"></div>
Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

Where bg1 and bg2 are the classes created for different backgrounds and pick a random bg class for the preloader div

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to put a quote into the CSS code. For example the code

```
echo "background:"."url(". $url."/images/loader-64x/infinity1.gif) center no-repeat #fff;";
```

will generate

```
"background": url(something/images/loader-64x/infinity1.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
```

Instead you need

```
echo "background:"."url(\"". $url."/images/loader-64x/infinity1.gif\") center no-repeat #fff;";
```

which will generate

```
"background": url("something/images/loader-64x/infinity1.gif") center no-repeat #fff;
```

Comment: I have tried but no pre loader is shown @Lajos Arpad

Comment: @user10065714 can you edit your question with the CSS code generated? Please take a look at page source in your browser.